# failed to open URLConnection in android

Tags: java, android, server, urlconnection

I'm trying to get the response code by opening a URLConnection, It was successfully making URLConnection in java console program, but when I tried this code in android this function always returns a -1 as resCode which means it couldn't able to make a URLConnection in android. Is there any solution to get website sever response code?

```
     public static int openHttpConnection(String urlStr) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int resCode=-1;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException ("URL is not an Http URL");
        }

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect(); 

        resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
        if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
        }         
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", "MalformedURLException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", "IOException");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception: ", "UnknownException");
    }
    return resCode;
    }
```

I've set internet permission in the manifest     android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: There is no `-1` value in response code. Only `200` when http is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the connection twice. And **there is no** response code = `-1`. It will be returned as `200` when `HTTP` is OK. Try to open the connection with `HttpURLConnection` only and get the response code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

// get the response code, returns 200 if it's OK
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

if(responseCode == 200) {
    // response code is OK
    in = connection.getInputStream();
}else{
    // response code is not OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode()) method:

> Returns -1 if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

You either get a malformed HTTP response here, or your request throws an Exception, leaving `resCode` in its initial state.

Comment: int i=openHttpConnection("google.com");
  statustext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
  statustext.setText("Status"+i);                            this is how I invoked the function. I've already tried with  http://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before.

I put this at the beginning of my code

```
// To keep this example simple, we allow network access
// in the user interface thread
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

And It works.

Comment: If the problem is `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, this only hides it and doesn't fix the underlying problem - network calls on main thread.

Comment: New : Android doesn't permit us to access internet via main UI thread. Try AsyncTask to do something with internet. My code before is used to gain permission to access internet in main UI thread, but this is not recommended